# C# Language updates

Tags: c#

How often has the C# language standard been updated and what is the current version?

Answer (score 2):

There are no ECMA/ISO standards for C# 3 or 4. Yet. But I somehow doubt there ever will be, considering all the nasty politics.

As for the de facto standard compiler by Microsoft, C# 1 was in January 2002, C# 2 in November 2005, C# 3 in November 2006 and C# 4 just this April.

Mono, which is the runtime for Linux and OS X, has had C# 3 support since 2008, but C# 4 isn't out yet.

There's a [C# version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)#Versions) on Wikipedia.